# Date query in mongodb isn't working

Tags: mongodb, date

**Type of document**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("585232c2bbdfc4243ecf2670"),
    "field1" : "value1",
    "date" : "Mon Dec 19 2016 14:45:17 GMT+0530 (IST)",
    "field2" : "value2",
    "field3" : true
}
```

**Query used:**

```
db.myCollection.find({"date":{"$lt":new Date()}})
```

> I want to run this query on 12:05 AM to fetch all past records upto
>   yesterday 23:59:59

Comment: How did you create that date ? Mongo db saves dates only in UTC. Save as a date field not as string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the value is a string and not a `Date`.

fields of type `Date` should appear like this:

```
"date" : ISODate("2016-12-19T14:45:17.000Z");
```

and not like what you're seeing.

Make sure you save a `Date` object into the collection, and not a string representation of it.